# Error in implementing push notification on Android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, push-notification, capacitor

I am creating an ionic-angular app. I tried to use push notification with the capacitor plugin. But I got an error like this. Can anyone help me?

```
**"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: "PushNotifications" plugin is not implemented on android
Error: "PushNotifications" plugin is not implemented on android"**
```

Comment: please share capacitor version

Comment: "@capacitor/android": "^3.1.2",
    "@capacitor/core": "^3.1.2",
    "@capacitor/ios": "^3.1.2",
    "@capacitor/push-notifications": "^1.0.3",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your MainActivity.java within your project. In the last version of Capacitor you have to remove the code "onCreate".

See: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/3-0#switch-to-automatic-android-plugin-loading

Answer (score 1):

I resolved **"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: "PushNotifications" plugin is not implemented on android
Error: "PushNotifications" plugin is not implemented on android"** error please follow below step

Add google-service.json file inside android/app folder

add this code in .ts file

```
import {
  ActionPerformed,
  PushNotificationSchema,
  PushNotifications,
  Token,
} from '@capacitor/push-notifications';
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';

constructor(public platform: Platform) {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.pushAdded();
    })
  }




pushAdded() {
    // Request permission to use push notifications
    // iOS will prompt user and return if they granted permission or not
    // Android will just grant without prompting
    PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then(result => {
      if (result.receive === 'granted') {
        // Register with Apple / Google to receive push via APNS/FCM
        PushNotifications.register();
      } else {
        // Show some error
      }
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener('registration', (token: Token) => {
      alert('Push registration success, token: ' + token.value);
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', (error: any) => {
      alert('Error on registration: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener(
      'pushNotificationReceived',
      (notification: PushNotificationSchema) => {
        alert('Push received: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
      },
    );

    PushNotifications.addListener(
      'pushNotificationActionPerformed',
      (notification: ActionPerformed) => {
        alert('Push action performed: ' + JSON.stringify(notification));
      },
    );
  }
```

[image]

Comment: I have added those changes. but unfortunately, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by removing the android folder and re-add that. Then it worked. Thanks, Ravi Ashara for helping.